Get Schema from Azure Schema Registry given topic name
I'm trying to retrieve the relevant schema (at the current point in time) from a Schema Registry for a specific Eventhub in an Eventhub Namespace. I need to retrieve the schema ahead of subscribing to the EventHub so I process it to create a schema in the datastore I'm trying populate.
I know how to retrieve the schema if I have the schemaId (see Java code below), however if I have the EventHub name, how do I retrieve the schema id that I need to look for?
byte[] schemaBytes =  schemaRegistry.getSchema(schemaId).block().getDefinition().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

I'm able to retrieve the schema given a schema id, which can be pulled from Kafka headers when I subscribe, but I'd like to be able to retrieve the schema without subscribing to the given EventHub/topic.

There are currently two ways to retrieve a schema from a Schema Registry:

Through the schema ID, as you mentioned.
With the group name, schema name, and schema version.

There is no way to retrieve a schema with just the Event Hub name or without the above information.

Thanks! this helps. Is there a way to retrieve the schema ID given an eventhub name, or is this not possible?

Schemas are not directly associated with an Event Hub, so this is not possible unless you know ahead of time that a specific schema is associated with a specific Event Hub.
